# 15 year old needs workout plan and help

Tags: workout

First off, this is my first post on the forum so sorry if I'm not doing something correct.

I would really appreciate help in finding a good home workout. I gave up doing workouts because the plan wasn't good. I can buy a pullup bar if needed.

- Age: 15 and a half years old
- Equipment: 2x0,7kg and a rope, but I'm able to buy other equipment if needed for better improvement
- Sports: I do no sports, I do go on my bike to school every morning and back, something like 8km a day.
- Physich: I've done some workouts in the past, my condition is ok
- Current heigh: 5"8 - 174 cm

Goals: Get stronger and improve Stamina. Also because I'm kinda skinny and want to change this.

I would highly appreciate some help!

Thom

Comment: It would help immensely if you outlined your goals, sports you do, expand on equipment and time available, etc. Just saying "help me work out" is incredibly broad. Current height, weight, experience, anything you can think of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for not giving direct answer. Partially that is because it is not my way, partially because I fill there is not enough information here.

First of all. Read. Watch youtube channels. How to distinguish if that particular one is good? Well, if they are PHDs, or referring other sources of information, that goes higher. If they say that advices are for all - they go down. All of us are different, and everyone needs to check what works, what is not - that is why I can't provide plan for you. So first advise is to build your own knowledge, by looking others, and trying their advices.

Write notes - to see progress. To have evidence what works what not. Our brain can be easily fulled, so notes are much better.

Buy a book. Something that gives you some kind of background, on which you can build your knowledge from blogs, vlogs. It can be [Kelly Starret](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1628600837), or something like that. Be sure to read criticism - to have better understanding... For the moment I'm reading about Myer's fascials.

If you do something do for both - antagonistic muscles. I mean you should train biceps, as well as triceps. That is important, since you don't have access to gym, equipment.

Think about push-ups, if you can do pull-ups - it would be great. Since that way you would train chest, and back. For abs I would propose plank. For legs - you can start with wall-sit. That is quite static set. But as starting point should be OK. Try to do 3-4 sets with 10-20 reps - for push-ups. For other exercises - try to have filling of same effort. Note that, and treat as starting point.

Having that of some time, perhaps 2-3 months I would advise to buy kettle-bell. Think about 15-18kg. Go to the shop or some other place, where you can grab one and try, which weight, and style fits you best. Idea is that you should not be able to keep it in your straight arm at eye level. To see exercises - find Pavel Tsatsouline. There are many videos at youtube, also there are his books, about kettle-bell, stretching.

So we have last point. Read about stretching, and do it. Long, full body stretching is quite stressful for your muscles, so do not put it with your normal load. To deal with it. Spend 10-20 min. at start or at the end. At start do fast, dynamic moves, to get more energy. At the end - slowdown, think about breathing, more yoga style. :) Stretching and mobilization can be something else. To mobilize buy roller, or small ball like for lacrosse. Fast moves on that will activate muscles, and your brain can imminently use new range of move. Do not do ballistic stretching, a specially at the end. That can end your training, or stop you for 2-3 months...

### Additional question:

I've watched so many vids, read so much information that Ive skipped workouts reading etc. I will definitely write notes. I don't quite understand the streatching point. Should I stretch before or after workout? Should those stretches be standard ones or is are there specific vids of it? Also I found this [plan](http://gyazo.com/6dcafa95740ec3580663c1a131fc8099) on forum.  I will do this until I found something better. - Thom :)

### ... and answers

I see you point. There is so much different videos saying "do this", "do that", or "ten steps to have great abs". What to do with it? Try, give it a try. Be careful, watch your body, but... if you don't have clear clue, just try it and check if that works for you.

About plan from gyazo. In first section I would move Burpees just after Jumping Jacks. Start with something easy like jumps, and then use most complicated exercises. That, which are heavy, or that which uses many muscles, moves many joints. I would use same start for second part. Later on you can change / shuffle it. Your body will learn the order, so please be sure to change it - let's say every 2-4 weeks.

About stretching. I can't recall the book. But I've red that strong, static stretching gives more stress to your muscles. That can pull down your scores, and give more soreness. However if you do mobilization - like with roller - it can be beneficial. For squat you can do something like [this](http://youtube.com/watch?v=lbozu0DPcYI) - just 10 moves of a kind, without that 30s and longer holds. Concentrate on correctness, and speed. Deep of move will come later. Then jumping jacks ...

After training you can do slow stretching, concentrate on position, breath. Going a bit deeper when exhaling... But be careful, and do not do too much. I've tried to do 45 min stretching after normal 50 min training soreness was doubled, so I've stopped. Idea is that not always more is better.

As @JohnP spotted. By stretching you give some motion range, and it is good idea to let your brain, and body be aware of that. So separate stretching session can give less then short, fast sessions before actual training. To get it - you need to concentrate on muscles you are going to train, and use dynamic stretching.

As a side note. Dynamic stretching and static are addressing different problems. What I wanted to say is to be aware that when you train your muscles it is good to stretch at same time.

### another question

I've found this video for [pre workout](http://youtube.com/watch?v=1RZ0WUn8S34), and this one for [after workout](http://youtube.com/watch?v=2wMSSupoCI8), are they ok/good? This is how my [workout](http://gyazo.com/6559e6c7a0aa27585a1abad9a7ec0dc8) looks like now.

### and answer.

Start doing, and watch your body. Do not stress yourself too much. Your initial target is to hold on doing it for 2 months. In that time, you will develop better understanding, muscles, neural connections - all that is needed to carry on.

According to pre workout stretching. Be careful with straight leg kicks. That is ballistic move, you are young, so it should not be a problem, but do that at the end of stretching, when your legs, are wormed enough. Other point - try to kip pelvis in a line. When one leg is in front, it should not influence on pelvis, spine. That is why there are mirrors at the gym. :)  On the other side - you are training under your weight, you are young - so just start, and do. Remember about notes. Hope to see some comments from you in a month or so!

And some more links from NSCA youtube:

- [bridge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5kbGUMwsWw)
- [dynamic warmup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUKZQix9x_E)
- [dynamic exercises, without equipment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gs8ePEvDLY&t=1575s)

Comment: First of all thank you very much for replying! I've watched so many vids, read so much information that Ive skipped workouts reading etc. I will definitely write notes. I don't quite understand the streatching point. Should I stretch before or after workout? Should those stretches be standard ones or is are there specific vids of it? Also I found this on the forum: https://gyazo.com/6dcafa95740ec3580663c1a131fc8099 I will do this until I found something better. - Thom :)

Comment: Dynamic stretching that mimics the activity is for before. Static stretching (sit and reach type) is for after, and has been proven to have a negative impact when done before.

Comment: @Michal Zaborowski I've found this video for pre workout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RZ0WUn8S34 and this one for after workout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wMSSupoCI8 are they ok/good? This is how my workout looks like now: https://gyazo.com/6559e6c7a0aa27585a1abad9a7ec0dc8

Comment: Thank you very much, I will start tomorrow. It will be probally be hard at first but I'm ready. I will try to eat even more healthier, drink more water for better progress. So I will change the order in 2-4 weeks but The jumping jacks and burpees do have to be the first right? Also I will just do the workout 3 times a week. In 2 months I will probally come back and try to look for another schedule if needed. I will deffinitely let you know -Thom

Comment: + for endurance 2 time a week should I do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uVaKjtJHN8&t=565s&index=12&list=PLfrYv6q22bLYZOujyCI-aLka-QjeSEcZp or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCqWeAL2xb4&t=846s&index=5&list=PLfrYv6q22bLYZOujyCI-aLka-QjeSEcZp